OpenSearch only accept tokens from the default Cognito app client?
So I created opensearch vpc access and then used an instance as a proxy to log into opensearch.
By default opensearch creates an App client and attaches it to the identity pool.
Right now my issue is I created another app client and added it to the identity pool.
Now I tried using that to log into opensearch and it returns this
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 5f355458-e7bc-4556-9adb-5f9d52925723; Proxy: null)
The second app client is a ditto of the one created by Opensearch.
Am I doing something wrong? Is it only accessible by the one created by opensearch itself?
